# How much is 175 lux (at 0 distance) when converted to cd/m2?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I have a lux meter and I'm trying to see how bright my display is compared to displays in reviews. But they all use cd/m2. What is 175 lux at 0 distance when converted to cd/m2?

I've googled and searched but could find no easy equation or anything that made sense to me.

Comment: They are both the same unit according to https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/light/candela-to-lux-calculator.html

Comment: Isn't it the same thing ($1 \ lx=1 \ cd/m^2$)?

Comment: They are equal only if metering from 1 meter away from the source, according to my reading. If put in a small distance unit like .01m the nits get extremely low, something like .0016 But on very respected sites such as notebookcheck they are using cd/m2 and getting numbers like 300.